# Hierarchical indexing with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame`with three index levels and two columns. You can see part of it here:

```
                        av_intensity  std_dev
key1 key2  time                        
0     0    32000          -0.005203  0.006278
           32200           0.005330  0.005221
           32400           0.002679  0.005006
           32600          -0.000723  0.006145
           32800          -0.000317  0.010467
           33000          -0.006543  0.007808
           33200          -0.004180  0.005070
           33400          -0.006275  0.009662
           33600          -0.014763  0.006938
           33800          -0.029516  0.004710
```

The indices are numbers, e.g. `(0.0, 0, 32000.0)` is a set of indices.

I am trying to use `df.ix[ 0.0, :, 32000.0]` or `df.ix[ :, 0, 32000]` to do some kind of hierarchical indexing but it doesn't work.

**Is it because the indices are not integer?**

**How can I do this kind of hierarchical indexing with this data frame?**

Comment: Use pd.to_clipboard and paste the first 10 rows into your question.

Answer (score 0):

See the advanced hierarchical indexing section in the docs for a full explanation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index

But basically, you cannot use slices (`:`) like that within a multi-index key. What you can do is by creating `:` as `slice(None)`:

```
dataGroupd.loc[(0.0, slice(None), 32000.0),:]
```

or use the `IndexSlice` convenience object that lets you write plain `:`'s:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
dataGroupd.loc[idx[0.0, :, 32000.0],:]
```

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I am using version 0.12

Comment: Ah, this is only available starting from 0.14.0. Are you able to upgrade? Another option is to use `xs` then